I have a hashkey conversion in synapse how to convert the same in redshift
HashKey in Synapse - CONVERT(char(64),HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',UPPER('1' + '|' +  ISNULL(CAST([SourceSystem] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'UNKNOWN') + '|' +  ISNULL(CAST([Vendor] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'UNKNOWN')  )),2)
I tried same in redshift as
sha2(UPPER('1' || '|' ||  NVL(CAST(SourceSystem AS VARCHAR(MAX)),'UNKNOWN') || '|' ||  NVL(CAST(Vendor AS VARCHAR(MAX)),'UNKNOWN')),256)
but the hashkeys are not matching.
Hashkey in Synapse - A92F254C476AB0DA1F0232697673B179832E7F6AC5BFCC831A318CE56CD80AB9
Hashkey in Redshift - 1f70da140d859ac783d4e9003df546673e485a5b391955c84f8f0a54f112a613

You didn’t convert the Redshift value to base64.
That said you will likely need to decompose the parts of this input string to verify that the text is the same going into the SHA.  Once verified the same, then compare the SHA results, then the base 64 results.
